# SQL Running Percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in an MySQL database:

### User_ID |  Film  |  Choice

Where choice is either 1 or 0. I would like to create a google chart with the percentage choice (1s) after each film. I can produce this in excel as below:

[image: excel]

Is there a way to produce a result which has these running totals, without creating a new column in the table? (similar to SUM)

First row should be 1 but set to 0 just to make the graph look better!

Comment: I think something along the line of "Select … (Count(Answer) / Count(*)) As Avg" might work for you.

Comment: Why is the first result 0? Why is the second result 0.5% - or should that be 50% !?! Either way, why?

Comment: I just set the first one as 0 so I didnt get an odd looking graph!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming @fancyPants is right (ususally is), then you can also write that this way (slightly simpler and less scalable)...

```
SELECT x.*
     , SUM(y.choice)/COUNT(*) * 100 pct 
  FROM film_choice x 
  JOIN film_choice y 
    ON y.film <= x.film 
 GROUP 
    BY x.film;
```

Comment: How would I include a WHERE clause in this, allowing to select only a specific User_ID?

Comment: Without seeing your DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle), TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT, I couldn't really comment.

Answer (score 1):

The first row should be 100%, right? 1 vote, 1 yes equals 100%

```
create table runningp(id int auto_increment primary key, choice tinyint);

insert into runningp(choice) values (1),(0),(0),(1),(1),(0),(1),(1),(0),(0);

select r.*, @p:=@p+choice, @t:=@t+1, @p/@t as yes 
from runningp r, 
(select @p:=0, @t:=0) v
order by id;

+----+--------+---------------+----------+--------+
| id | choice | @p:=@p+choice | @t:=@t+1 | yes    |
+----+--------+---------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |             1 |        1 | 1.0000 |
|  2 |      0 |             1 |        2 | 0.5000 |
|  3 |      0 |             1 |        3 | 0.3333 |
|  4 |      1 |             2 |        4 | 0.5000 |
|  5 |      1 |             3 |        5 | 0.6000 |
|  6 |      0 |             3 |        6 | 0.5000 |
|  7 |      1 |             4 |        7 | 0.5714 |
|  8 |      1 |             5 |        8 | 0.6250 |
|  9 |      0 |             5 |        9 | 0.5556 |
| 10 |      0 |             5 |       10 | 0.5000 |
+----+--------+---------------+----------+--------+
```

To just select what you need:

```
select id, choice, yes from (
select r.*, @p:=@p+choice, @t:=@t+1, @p/@t as yes 
from runningp r, 
(select @p:=0, @t:=0) v
order by id
) sq
order by id;

+----+--------+--------+
| id | choice | yes    |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 | 1.0000 |
|  2 |      0 | 0.5000 |
|  3 |      0 | 0.3333 |
|  4 |      1 | 0.5000 |
|  5 |      1 | 0.6000 |
|  6 |      0 | 0.5000 |
|  7 |      1 | 0.5714 |
|  8 |      1 | 0.6250 |
|  9 |      0 | 0.5556 |
| 10 |      0 | 0.5000 |
+----+--------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So in this one a new table is created? It cannot be done in the same way as SUM (creating a temporary column)?

Comment: No, there's no new table created. You can also use Strawberry's solution. It's fine and easy to understand, but I'd guess that mine performs better when you have huge data amount.